# Dynamic option selection in bash?

Tags: bash, macos, command-line-interface

I've got a variable in the script that has several lines of single words

Say `$loremipsums` is basically this:

```
something1
something2
something3
something4
```

Now `$loremipsums` is dynamic; it can be more or less, and can be different values depending on what it reads from a certain file. I also want to use what the user chose in a variable.

I want to make them into an option selection menu dynamically. I found one that shows the basic one here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1705/how-can-i-create-a-select-menu-in-a-shell-script

Now I need to do it dynamically. As you can see, they're set manually through that example.

Here is an example of what I want:

```
1) michael
2) richard
3) steven
4) robert
5) exit
Please enter your choice: 4
You have chosen robert
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To split $loremipsums on newlines, and select one of them:

```
oldIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
choices=( $loremipsums )
IFS=$oldIFS
PS3="Please enter your choice: "
select answer in "${choices[@]}"; do
  for item in "${choices[@]}"; do
    if [[ $item == $answer ]]; then
      break 2
    fi
  done
done
echo "$answer"
```

Answer (score 13):

Do you know `select` ?

```
names=( michael richard steven robert exit )
select name in "${names[@]}"; do
    echo "You have chosen $name"
    [[ $name == exit ]] && break
done
```